# Numba and Numpy Random Number interaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, numba

I am trying to generate a bunch of random numbers quickly to do a MCMC.

I have the following benchmarks:

```
@njit
def getRandos(n):
    for i in prange(n):
        a = np.random.rand()


%timeit np.random.rand(1000000000)
13.1 s ± 287 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit getRandos(1000000000)
1.97 s ± 25.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Clearly the parallelization improves my runtime.  However, I don't know how the seeding of the random number generation works.  How can I ensure that these numbers are truly random?  Do I have to randomly choose a seed somehow?

Comment: Why do you need a random seed? Seed is your control knob

Comment: I am parallelizing it and I want to ensure that each thread is returning truly random numbers

Comment: There are no truly random numbers in either numpy or numba - all of them are pseudo-random number generators. By controlling seeds you shall ensure the non-overlapping between threads random numbers sequences

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an apples to apples comparison. The first call you make `np.random.rand(1000000000)` is spending a ton of time creating space and storing the random numbers, while the second call `getRandos(1000000000)` just generates values and drops them.

Here is the apples to apples comparison (which is about the same speed):

```py
from numba import prange, njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def getRandos(n):
    a = np.zeros(n)
    for i in prange(n):
        a[i] = np.random.rand()
    return a

%timeit -n 100 getRandos(100000)
%timeit -n 100 np.random.rand(100000)
```

To answer your question however, reference the numba documentation [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#random).

They don't allow you to create individual RandomState instances, but you can set the seed inside the definition.

```py
@njit
def getRandos(n):
    np.random.seed(1111)
    a = np.zeros(n)
    for i in prange(n):
        a[i] = np.random.rand()
    return a


values = getRandos(100000)
values2 = getRandos(100000)
print(all(values == values2))  # True
```